# Existence of the partition of unity subordinate to the patches covering a surface

Tags: integration, definition, differential-forms, surfaces

I am studying (Zorich, Mathematical Analysis II, Chapter 13) the integration of differential forms on orientable smooth surfaces in $ \mathbb {R}^n $ and I have some doubts about the definitions.
My textbook does not seem to me to give a precise definition (or maybe I don't see it well) of what it means to integrate a differential k-form on an orientable smooth k-surface $S$, when $S$ cannot be described by a single chart, but searching a bit I seem to have understood that the correct definition to be taken into consideration should be the following:

$$\int_S \omega := \sum_i \int_{U_{k(i)}} \alpha_i \cdot \omega$$

where $\{\alpha_i(x)\}_i$ is a family of continuous functions (at most countable) with compact support defined on $S$ such that for every $i$ we can always find a patch $U_{k(i)}\subset S$ in the atlas of $S$ such that $\text{supp }\alpha_i\subset U_{k(i)}$. In other words, $\{\alpha_i(x)\}_i$ is a partition of unity defined on $S$.

First question: is there a theorem that guarantees me that such a family of functions can always be constructed, regardless of the atlas chosen for $ S $?

Second question: could $\sum_i[...]$ be infinite? If yes, how can I justify its convergence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zorich's book so I can't point to a specific page, but several books deal with this. For example, Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced calculus book (chapter 10) talks about partitiions of unity, Spivak's calculus on manifolds also has a proof of existence, as I'm sure any other serious book does. For second question, if $\omega$ has compact support then it is really a finite sum of terms (all others are 0), and since $\alpha_i$ has compact support, so does $\alpha_i\cdot\omega$, so $\int_{U_{k(i)}}\alpha_i\cdot \omega$ is finite. So the total sum is still finite.

Comment: More generally, one can define a form to be integrable if the series you write (with absolute values instead) is finite. One can then show (this is done in Spivak) that nothing depends on the particular choices made.